# How do I set an image as the background of a path in d3.js?

Tags: image, svg, background, d3.js, geometry

First time using d3.js and am experimenting with using this example: http://bl.ocks.org/christophermanning/1734663 in a site I'm making, but I want the fill of the shapes to be images instead of a purple color.

I think the relevant code is inside the update function as follows:

```
    path = path.data(d3_geom_voronoi(vertices))
    path.enter().append("path")
        // drag node by dragging cell
        .call(d3.behavior.drag()
          .on("drag", function(d, i) {
              vertices[i] = {x: vertices[i].x + d3.event.dx, y: vertices[i].y + d3.event.dy}
          })
        )
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(0) })
    path.attr("d", function(d) { return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z"; })
        .transition().duration(150).style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d3.geom.polygon(d).area()) })
    path.exit().remove();
```

So first I comment out..

```
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d3.geom.polygon(d).area()) })
```

..so my image fill wont be overwritten on update, and then I need to replace..

```
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(0) })
```

..with "something", but before I replace it I define the image by adding..

```
var image = svg.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "http://lorempixel.com/g/400/400/")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 400)
  .attr("id", "fillImage");
```

..before the update function, and then I've tried replacing the fill code with stuff like:

```
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return "url('#fillImage')" })
```

or

```
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return "url(#fillImage)" })
```

or

```
  .style("fill", "url('#fillImage')")
```

or

```
  .style("fill", "url(#fillImage)")
```

or all the same except using "attr" instead of "style", as well as not using an id but the image varible, so: image, image[0], image[0][0], image[0][0].outerHTML. But nothing seems to work, so any ideas?

Comment: The `url(#fillImage)` approach should work, but you have to append the image to a `<defs>` node within the SVG, whereas currently you're appending it directly to the `<svg>`. Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/vitch/3226952) for guidance.

Comment: Ever find a way to dynamically add images to the path backgrounds? The suggestion above is interesting, but seems like a def for every image, not dynamic?

Comment: It's a pain that this seems undocumented elsewhere, but the following has worked for me in the past. It was tried in desperation:

`.attr("style", "fill:url(#fillImage)")`